# PHP ODBC execute is trying to open a file

Tags: php, csv, odbc, teradata

For some reason this code is causing `odbc_execute();` to attempt to open a file...

```
$file = fopen('somefile.csv', 'r');
fgetcsv($file); // Skip the first line
$data = [];
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) != false) {
    $data[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);

try {
    $conn = odbc_connect("Teradata", "User", "Pass");
    odbc_autocommit($conn, false);

    odbc_exec($conn, 'DELETE FROM table');

    foreach ($data as &$test) {
        $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'INSERT INTO table (experiment_code, experiment_name, variant_code, variant_name, version_number, report_start_date, report_end_date, status, transaction_date, experiment_test_id, test_manager, product_manager, pod, created_date, last_updated_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        odbc_execute($stmt, $test);
    }

    odbc_commit($conn);

    $result = odbc_exec($conn, 'SELECT * FROM table');
    odbc_result_all($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    odbc_rollback($conn);
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is a snip-it of the CSV file...

```
H1225,Some random text,H1225:001.000,Control,3,02/06/2014,03/31/2014,Completed,,HMVT-1225,Some random name,Some random name,Checkout,03/31/2014 16:54,02/06/2014 16:38
H1225,Some random text,H1225:001.000,Control,3,02/06/2014,03/31/2014,Completed,,HMVT-1225,Some random name,Some random name,Checkout,03/31/2014 16:54,02/06/2014 16:38
```

And here is the type of error I am getting...

```
Warning: odbc_execute(): Can't open file Control in C:\wamp\www\HEXinput\assets\php\dumpCSV.php on line 19
```

I get multiple version of the same error just with a different file name. The file name seems to be coming from column 3 (0 based). Another weird thing is that it actually does insert some lines correctly.

The final error I get is...

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\HEXinput\assets\php\dumpCSV.php on line 27
```

I am using Teradatas ODBC Drivers for version 15 on windows 7 64bit.

What could be causing this?

Comment: are you sure that's properly formed csv? "some random text" doesn't look promising. if that contains any `,`, you'll be throwing off the array because the csv parser found "more" fields than there really should be.

Comment: I believe it is.. How could I double check?

Comment: `echo count($line)` and see if all the lines have the same counts. any mis-parses will almost certainly throw that off.

Comment: Nope all the lines have the same count of 15

Comment: I have added to my question slightly as i have noticed that it's always on column 3 if were talking 0 based...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that some of the fields in the CSV file had single quotes in them which broke the query.

Simple but annoying oversight.